# Custom CSS doesn't work in edit mode

Tags: themes, css

I'm using Wordpress 5.6.1 with Twenty Twenty-One theme.  I have added some additional CSS and it works fine for published posts.  But it does not apply while I'm editing a post.  In Chrome web inspector, I can see my changes in the style list, but they are stricken through.  Why does this happen?  I have tried incognito mode to make sure it's not a caching issue.  The customization is just this:

```
blockquote>p {
    font-weight: unset;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 8px;
}

blockquote:before {
    content: none !important;
}
```

In the inspector, it looks like these rules are taking precedence even though I tried adding `!important` to each property.  I don't see anything that would overrule my border.

```
.editor-styles-wrapper .wp-block-quote:before {
    content: "“";
}

editor-styles-wrapper .wp-block-quote p {
    font-family: var(--quote--font-family);
    font-size: var(--quote--font-size);
    font-style: var(--quote--font-style);
    font-weight: var(--quote--font-weight);
    line-height: var(--quote--line-height);
}
```

Comment: Welcome! If you can see the styles are stricken, what is the rule that is taking precedence? You could always try to make a style that's more specific than that.